# MySQL C pdb files

Tags: mysql, c, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm using the mysqlclient.lib static library for a C project I am making in visual studio 2010. The program builds fine but when I try and debug my program the breakpoints are hollowed out and say "the breakpoint will not currently be hit. no symbols have been loaded for this document". I've included the debug version of the mysqlclient.lib however I get a bunch of linker warnings when building.

```
mysqlclient.lib(sha.obj) : warning LNK4099: PDB 'taocrypt.pdb' was not found with 
'mysqlclient.lib(sha.obj)' or at '/my project directory'\taocrypt.pdb'; linking 
object as if no debug info
```

And I get that warning for about 7-8 obj files per pdb file.
The pdb files that aren't found are `taocrypt.pdb, yassl.pdb, zlib.pdb, mysys.pdb, strings.pdb, dbug.pdb, clientlib.pdb`. Am I supposed to include these pdb files in my project somehow? There's a mysqlclient.pdb file that comes with the mysqlclient.lib but I don't know what to do with it. What am I supposed to do with it?

Cheers.

Comment: Try placing your pdb file in the same folder as the .lib file and then compiling it.

Comment: Compiling what, the program or the lib? The pdb and lib files are already in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://bryanhinton.com/docs/mysql/5.0/news.html). 
It says "On Windows, symbols for yaSSL and taocrypt were missing from mysqlclient.lib, resulting in unresolved symbol errors for clients linked against that library. (Bug#27861)"
So you can try upgrading to a later version of MySQL (after 5.0.48) and see if the problem occurs.

Comment: I'm using the library from MySQL 5.5.9